# Problem with saving as PDF, problem with file name

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have such problem with my Code, I have error like this below:

```vb
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=20
Selection.Expand wdLine
Selection.Font.Color = -603914241
    
strDocName = (Selection.Text)

ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
    "\\tsclient\D\" & strDocName & ".pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
    OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:= _
    wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
    IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, CreateBookmarks:= _
    wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, BitmapMissingFonts:= _
    True, UseISO19005_1:=False
ChangeFileOpenDirectory "\\tsclient\D\"
```

I have error like this

> Run time error 2147467259 (8004005)

Really need help this is my last step and it's failing

Comment: Which line throws the error? What is the error text? What is the content of `strDocName`? Is it a valid file name? Do you have write access to the destination folder? Can you write a file with that name manually (without VBA)? Does a file with that name already exists that you can't overwrite?

Comment: Error is in last line with saving file. Manually with write file name there is no problem. There is no file with this name

Comment: The Selection which should be strDocName is just client name and invoice number, and its appear in right way in VBA, but when it come to save it, boom error

Comment: yes it has name, maybe you can tell me how to overwrite it,?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69451374/selecting-text-problem-with-saving-document-word